# Should I use "and", "with", "of", and/or "between"?

Tags: sentence-structure

**What is the best structure for this title? Are they all correct?**

1- Comparison ***of*** Surgical Outcomes and Intraopertive
Complications ***of*** Endoscopic ***with*** Conventional Septoplasty

2- Comparison ***between*** Surgical Outcomes and Intraopertive
Complications ***of*** Endoscopic ***and*** Conventional Septoplasty

3-Comparison ***of*** Surgical Outcomes and Intraopertive Complications ***between*** Endoscopic ***and*** Conventional Septoplasty

Comment: @RyanM - Comparing the sentences, it seems the question is focused on how to use "of"/"with"/"and"/"between" which requires no specialized knowledge.  I've edited the question and highlighted the words Samy seems to be interested in having a better understanding of.

Comment: @RichardWinters Your edit helped clarify a lot, thanks.  I've deleted my original comment, as it no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 uses **of** twice, which makes it a little confusing.

I think sentence 2 introduces **between** too early:  it sounds as if you are comparing the outcomes with the complications.

Positioning **between** immediately before the two procedures seems to me the clearest:

```
Comparison of Surgical Outcomes and Intraopertive Complications
between Endoscopic and Conventional Septoplasty.
```

Your sentence 3 in fact.